# Bluetooth hci0 device suddenly missing on 4B

Tags: bluetooth, serial, pi-4, bluez

After a recent reboot of my 4B I noticed that my bluetooth connections had stopped working. I noticed that `bluetoothctl` reported no device, and further that `sudo hciconfig hci0 up` indicates `Can't get device info: No such device`. Based upon threads [like this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=171999), I checked `sudo systemctl status hciuart` and don't see anything obviously wrong:

```
● hciuart.service - Configure Bluetooth Modems connected by UART
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/hciuart.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2019-11-13 11:17:12 EST; 4h 22min ago
 Main PID: 674 (hciattach)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 1.5M
   CGroup: /system.slice/hciuart.service
           └─674 /usr/bin/hciattach /dev/serial1 bcm43xx 3000000 flow -

Nov 13 11:17:04 spellbook-van systemd[1]: Starting Configure Bluetooth Modems connected by UART...
Nov 13 11:17:12 spellbook-van btuart[331]: bcm43xx_init
Nov 13 11:17:12 spellbook-van btuart[331]: Flash firmware /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM4345C0.hcd
Nov 13 11:17:12 spellbook-van btuart[331]: Set Controller UART speed to 3000000 bit/s
Nov 13 11:17:12 spellbook-van btuart[331]: Device setup complete
Nov 13 11:17:12 spellbook-van systemd[1]: Started Configure Bluetooth Modems connected by UART.
```

I've confirmed that `/dev/serial` is a symlink:

`/dev/lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Nov 13 11:17 /dev/serial1 -> ttyAMA0`.

I suspect I messed something up when attempting to configure a USB GPS device via `gpsd` on `/dev/ttyACM0`. My best guess is that I accidentally ran some command against `/dev/ttyAMA0` instead of `/dev/ttyACM0`, but I can't think of what it may have been or what I might do to continue debugging. However, I'll note that `sudo cat /dev/ttyAMA0` returns successfully but no output.

Comment: If you don't know how you broke it, neither do we. Just do what the rest of us would do - **restore from your backup**.

Comment: @Milliways It's reasonable to ask for what steps should next be tried for debugging purposes. "Restoring from backups" is a nuclear option that teaches nothing. That's what we're here for, to learn, not to blindly press the buttons that make it work.

Comment: There is no Raspberry Pi version 4B+, it's only 4B.

Comment: @ZaneClaes If you wish to learn start again, **record**  changes, make **backups** of all changed system files and you and we have some chance of answering.